# Split button /Combo box button like in eclipse

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, split-button

I would create a combo box / split button similar like the debug/run button in eclipse. I tried to use BasicComboBoxUI but it changes the Look and Feel. Is there any possible way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution and it works great.

http://java.dzone.com/news/drop-down-buttons-swing-new-al